# Exception on JSON-PATCH post to @RepositoryRestResource in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-mvc, json-patch

I can't get Spring Data REST to accept a JSON-PATCH content body, what am I doing wrong?

Simple domain:

```
@Document
public class DomainA {
    @Id private String id;
    private String atext;
    public String getAtext(){ return atext;}
    public void setAtext(String str){ atext = str;}
}
```

Backed by a MondoDB repo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface DomainARepository extends MongoRepository<DomainA, String> {}
```

I want to JSON-PATCH this,like so:

```
curl -X PATCH -H "Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpQVw=="
-H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json"
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache"
-d '[{"op":"replace", "path":"/atext", "value":"JSON-PATCHed text"}]' 
http://localhost:8080/domainAs/550e169209a5cc0df82c95d4
```

But when I do I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
Could not read an object of type class patchex.DomainA from the request!;
nested exception is
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
Could not read payload!; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode cannot be cast to
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode at
    org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.readPatch(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:183)
```

....

If I supply the patch body without the array brackets, I get back a 204; no exception but no change to the document, either. I can "patch" the document using `PUT` or `PATCH` of `{"atext":"PUTed value"}`; POSTs/GETs work fine; and, the tests in Spring Data REST seem to verify that JSON-PATCH *should* work if I can get the content body accepted. So, what's the right way to using PATCH here?

(Using Spring Boot 1.2.2.RELEASE starters for -data-mongodb, -data-rest, java 1.8)

EDIT: Same exception if I back with a JPA (H2) CRUD @RepositoryRestResource repo.

EDIT: Opened JIRA at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-498